# Call to a member function move() on string when uploading File

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-router, react-router-dom

My laravel backend can't upload or move a file in my directory **UPLOAD FOLDER**.  I think my file request is a string, that's why the **move upload** is not working. I don't know if that's the problem.

I am using `React JS` and `useLoader Data` and `Form`  from `react-router-dom`   as my frontend.
And customize `axiosClient`

Here is the error on `console.log`

**Network**

[image]

**Console.log**

[image]

Here is my export default **ProductAdd**

```
export default function ProductAdd(){
    const [image,setImage] = useState(null)

    const imageHandler = (e) =>{
       setImage(e.target.files[0])
    }

       return(<Form  id="clear-form" method="post" replace>
             <div className="mb-4 relative">
                  <label >
                        File Picture
                    </label>
                 <input name="image" onChange={imageHandler} type="file" />
                </div>
                <div>
                <button type="submit
                    Create
                </button>
           </Form>)
     }
```

Here is my export **ProductAddActionLoader**

```
export const ProductAddActionLoader = async({ request }) =>{

    const formData = await request.formData();
    const payload = {
        image:formData.get('image'),
    }

    return await axiosClient.post('admin/fruit/create',payload).
        then(({data})=>{
            console.log(data)
            return data
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.log(error)
            return error
        })
}
```

Here is my router.jsx

```
         path:'create',
         element:<ProductAdd/>,
         action:ProductAddActionLoader
```

Here is my `ProductController` in my backend

```
public function create(Request $request){

       //return $request->image;
        $fileName = time().'.'.$request->image;
        $request->image->move(public_path('uploads'), $fileName);
        return response('Data has been Added',200);
    }
```

but when i uncomment `return $request->image` the name of the picture is returning.
but this  `$request->image->move(public_path('uploads'), $fileName);` it's not working and not uploading in my directory path

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use multipart/form-data to upload files

```
return await axiosClient.post('admin/fruit/create', payload, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
}).
then(({data})=>{
    console.log(data)
    return data
}).catch(error=>{
    console.log(error)
    return error
})
```

Comment: thank you i already did this

Answer (score 0):

you can do it:

```php
Storage::disk('local')->put('uploads' . '/' . $fileName , $request->image);
```

Comment: it's returning empty string i use encType='multipart/form-data'

Answer (score 0):

I think you are transferring the file from js incorrectly, try transferring the file using this

```
 return await axiosClient.post('admin/fruit/create', formData)
```

instead of

```
 return await axiosClient.post('admin/fruit/create', payload)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).